# exc_bad_instruction(code=exc_i386_Invop subcode=0x0) xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using xcode with the language swift. I continue to get this error on all of my code. exc_bad_instruction(code=exc_i386_Invop subcode=0x0) xcode. I have seen other questions and none make sense. I'm not sure if it is because of the second view but here is the code. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGsD2.png)

It has two views so I don't know if thats the problem. I need help!

Comment: Check that your SEED IBOutlet is connected to the label.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the iboutlet is not connected in storyboard, because of which it is not getting initialised, no memory allocated to this object. Kindly check your storyboard connections.